# Как в Nuxt3 заставить сработать запрос useFetch() к api при перезагрузке страницы (F5)?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Функция useFetch() срабатывает только при клике по ссылке на страницу. Если перезагрузить нужную страницу на F5, то данные api не подгружаются. Как заставить Nuxt3 подгрузить данные?

Comment: Нашел ответ, который сработал для меня с аналогичной проблемой - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71609027/usefetch-in-onmounted-not-fetching-data-on-direct-link-open-nuxt3